# Keep containers running after build

Tags: docker-compose, teamcity

We are using the Docker Compose TeamCity build runner and would like the containers to continue running after the build.

I understand that the docker-compose build step itself follows a successful 'up' with a 'down', so I have attempted to bring them back up in a subsequent command line step with simply:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I can see from the log that this is initially successful but when the build process exits, so do the containers.  I have also tried:

```
nohup docker-compose up -d &
```

The outcome is the same.

How do we keep the containers running when the build has finished?

For info, the environment is both TeamCity and its BuildAgent running on the same Ubuntu box.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by NOT using the Docker Compose build runner.  I now just have a single command line build step doing:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d
```

This works, and I feel rather silly ;-)